# Generate heatmap rgba values python

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-science

I need to generate a list of color representation of numbers (kind of like a heatmap), but just the rgba values. Something that gets as input a list of numbers and return a set of rgba values representing these numbers. Is there a module that do this in python?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as a starting point, you could do something along these lines to make a function that returns an rgba for an input value, based on a predefined scale for the colormap:

```
from matplotlib.colors import cm

def get_rgba(value, limits, cmap):
    fac = (value-limits[0]) / (limits[1]-limits[0])
    return cmap(fac)

cmap = cm.get_cmap('jet')
limits = [0,10]
value  = 5.292

print(get_rgba(value, limits, cmap))
```

output:

```
(0.5787476280834913, 1.0, 0.38899430740037955, 1.0)
```